# HTML - Prevent Webcam Images From Being Cached

Tags: php, html, caching, webcam

I have several simple HTML web pages that display webcam images. The images are updated every four minutes. However, browsers cache the images so that users (and I) don't see the most recent image even after refreshing the page. I would like to prevent the images (or the entire page) from being cached without having to change the file name or extension or location of the files.

I have seen this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

But also this:

> meta http-equiv is highly unreliable

And, sure enough, it doesn't work.

Here's one of the pages: https://www.mgnewman.com/koratsky.html

I know I can do this with PHP, but that would require me to change the file extension which I do not want to do because the existing URL is widely distributed.

But, just for fun, I tried a .php file with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

But it doesn't work, either; at least with Safari on a Mac.

Is there any way I can do this so it actually works?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked:

```
<img src="https://www.mgnewman.com/koratsky.jpg?v=<?php echo 
Date("U")?>  alt="Korat Sky Image" id="responsive_image">
```

I had to change the file extension to php which means I'll have to redirect from the old .html file. But, it does indeed work:

[Korat Sky Kam](http://mgnewman.com/koratsky.php)